# Method for filtering out gps topic in a bag file

Tags: navigation, gps, rosbag, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I have recorded a bag file which contains gps topic for using with robot_localization pkg. I want to modify my gps topic to mimic a scenario where gps signal is not available, e.g transition from indoor to outdoor and vice versa. Using [topic tools](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools) I was able to drop/filter out my gps messages. The result is in the following picture:
[image: drop gps messages]

topic_tools drops X out of Y messages *regularly* as it is supposed to (blue dots). My question is: is there any method that can drop messages for ***a specific time length***? For clarification, I would like something like this:
[image: image description]

where the yellow lines are my gps messages and the gaps between them are dropped gps messages.
I appreciate your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285270/method-for-filtering-out-gps-topic-in-a-bag-file/) by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 358 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This cmd line would extract all messages on topic /odometry/gps between t1 and t2 and between t3 and t4 (you can keep extending it for other intervals). Is that what you want?

```
rosbag filter bag_in.bag bag_out.bag "topic == '/odometry/gps' and ((m.header.stamp.secs > t1 and m.header.stamp.secs < t2) or (m.header.stamp.secs > t3 and m.header.stamp.secs < t4))"
```

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-03-14**:
Yes, this is exactly what I need. Thank you for your help!

**Comment by [bmgatten](https://answers.ros.org/users/41434/bmgatten/) on 2019-09-24**:
This would filter out everything *except* the /odometry/gps from those times.  I think tuandl is asking how to  drop those messages instead of filtering everything else from the bagfile.